# Is it possible to copy and paste vertex weight?

Tags: scripting, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-paint

Is it possible to copy the vertex weight from 1 vertex on a body mesh, then paste that weight onto ALL the vertex of a selection (basically an accessory that's joined to the body for the purpose of pasting vertex weight), instead of 1 vertex at a time (that would take forever for any object unless it's a cube or something)? I found a copy/paste vertex script by Ivo Grigull but it's only for very old Blender versions (pre-2.4.9).

Also, whenever I manually copy/paste vertex weight (one at a time, was testing it with a cube), then later separate the cube from the rest of the body by selecting all vertices on the cube and press P, the body would get completely distorted (stretched to infinity in all directions).

[image]

Anyone know how to paste vertex weight onto multiple vertices, as well as why my weight-pasting doesn't work at all?

Comment: Can you add the blend file?

Answer (score 3):

In *Weight Paint Mode* you can set Weight by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

1. Toggle *Vertex Selection Masking* to select the vertices

[image]

2. Set the Weight (use @joshsanfelici technique to copy vertex value)
3. Press  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to set weight

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select your object, toggle into *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all vertices "destination", last <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the vertex you want to copy from.
<kbd>N</kbd> to open up the *Properties Panel*, click the "paste down arrow" in the *Vertex Weights* panel.

Note: *Vertex Weights* panel will displayed only in *Edit Mode* with a weighted vertex selected.

[image]